# Samba ports still closed even with iptables rules flushed and disabled

Tags: linux, networking, centos, iptables

I’m trying to install Samba on a server running CentOS 6 with WHM/cPanel, and I’m having some trouble with ports.

This is a brand new system as of yesterday, and I haven’t yet started locking down any ports on it or installing extra security software. To make debugging simper, I also flushed all `iptables` rules entirely:

```
# iptables -L
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

I’m able to reach things like the web server and SSH, but I can’t seem to send traffic over port `139` or `445`.

Using `netstat` I confirmed that nothing is using either of those ports, and then used `nc -l 0.0.0.0 139` to listen on port `139`. I’m unable to send any data to it from outside. If I change to port `140`, everything goes through fine. Most other ports are usable, but interestingly all Samba-related ports exhibit this same behavior:

```
PORT    STATE    SERVICE
130/tcp closed   cisco-fna
131/tcp closed   unknown
132/tcp closed   cisco-sys
133/tcp closed   statsrv
134/tcp closed   unknown
135/tcp filtered msrpc
136/tcp filtered profile
137/tcp filtered netbios-ns
138/tcp filtered netbios-dgm
139/tcp filtered netbios-ssn
140/tcp closed   unknown

440/tcp closed   sgcp
441/tcp closed   decvms-sysmgt
442/tcp closed   cvc_hostd
443/tcp open     https
444/tcp closed   snpp
445/tcp filtered microsoft-ds
446/tcp closed   ddm-rdb
447/tcp closed   ddm-dfm
448/tcp closed   ddm-ssl
449/tcp closed   as-servermap
450/tcp closed   tserver
```

The server is hosted by Linode, and their support people insist that their data center isn’t doing any filtering that would be causing this. Samba is set to bind to all interfaces (`0.0.0.0`), but this happens even if I take Samba out of the equation and open my own sockets with netcat.

What else could I be missing? Is there something besides `iptables` that could be dropping traffic on certain ports?

Comment: Samba is set to bind to all interfaces (0.0.0.0), but this happens even if I take samba out of the equation and open my own sockets with netcat.

Comment: ``nc -l 0.0.0.0`` should listen port on all interfaces;) Because nobody (except viruses and hackers) do CIFS/SMB connections over Internet may ISPs close such ports. Use another port and do ``-j REDIRECT`` on iptables.

Answer (score 0):

While looking into some things @user996142 mentioned, I realized that while I've engaged Linode about their firewall, I hadn't looked as closely at the one here in the office. It turns out that our ISP is indeed blocking ports 135-139 and 445. There's one other server we've used a similar setup with (which is why I simply assumed it would work with another server), but its connection goes through VPN, while this new server does not.